# conky using a function call within an if statement

Tags: linux, lua, conky

How do I call a function after loading it in conkyrc?  For example:

I'm trying to get the active interface name which is returning properly

```
${lua conky_findInterface} #gives me device name

function conky_findInterface()
  local handle = io.popen('ip a | grep "state UP" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " "')
  local result = handle:read('*a'):gsub('\n$','')
  handle:close()
  return result
end
```

How do I use it more dynamically?  Such as :

```
${if_up ${lua_parse "${lua conky_findInterface}"}} #this does not work nor do my other variations
Hello
${else}
Goodbye
${endif}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a conky if statement argument can't be a string, so a string returned by a Lua function won't work. For example, where my interface is "enp2s0", the statement `${if_up enp2s0}` will work, but `${if_up "enp2s0"}` will not.

A workaround is to include the entire conky if statement in a Lua function. For example:

```
function findInterface()
  local handle = io.popen('ip a | grep "state UP" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " "')
  local result = handle:read('*a'):gsub('\n$','')
  handle:close()
  return result
end

function conky_ifupInterface()
  local ifup = "${if_up " .. findInterface() .. "}"
  ifup = ifup .. "Hello${else}"
  ifup = ifup .. "Goodbye${endif}"
  return ifup
end
```

The function `conky_ifupInterface()` is then called in `conkyrc` with the line:

```
${lua_parse conky_ifupInterface}
```

Unfortunately, just returning the first line of the if statement isn't sufficient to satisfy the `lua_parse` operator. The entire statement through the `${endif}` has to be returned.

Note that the current implementation of `findInterface` will cause the conky config to crash on a call to `conky_ifupInterface` if the interface is down because `findInterface` will return a null value, resulting in the if statement beginning with `${if_up }`. To make it work for testing, I did the following quick and dirty bit...

```
function findInterface()
  local handle = io.popen('ip a | grep "state UP" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " "')
  local result = handle:read('*a'):gsub('\n$','')
  handle:close()
  if result == "" then
    handle = io.popen('ip a | grep "state DOWN" | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d " "')
    result = handle:read('*a'):gsub('\n$','')
    handle:close()
  end
  return result
end
```

Yuck! I'm sure you can do better. :^)